# Add the values of two tables based on a combination of columns

Tags: pandas

I have two tables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "c_id": [2000,3000,3000], 
    "cloud":["GCP","GCP","Azure"], 
    "invoice":[100,100,300]
})

c_id    cloud   invoice
2000    GCP     100
3000    GCP     100
3000    Azure   300

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "c_id": [1000,2000,2000,3000,3000], 
    "cloud":["Azure","GCP","Azure","AWS","Azure"], 
    "invoice":[200,200,300,100,100]
})

c_id    cloud   invoice
1000    Azure   200
2000    GCP     200
2000    Azure   300
3000    AWS     100
3000    Azure   100
```

I want to add the two tables based on the combination of columns `c_id` and `cloud`. The result I'm looking for is:

```
c_id    cloud   invoice
1000    Azure   200
2000    Azure   300
2000    GCP     300
3000    AWS     100
3000    Azure   400
3000    GCP     100
```

In my example, I only displayed the column `invoice`. In my actual dataset, there are actually more than 40 columns with a lot more constraints. Several of the columns only have value when the `cloud` is `Azure`, while others only have value when the `cloud` is either `Azure` or `GCP`

Is there's a clean way to add `df1` and `df2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "c_id": [2000,3000,3000], 
    "cloud":["GCP","GCP","Azure"], 
    "invoice":[100,100,300]
})
print (df1)
   c_id  cloud  invoice
0  2000    GCP      100
1  3000    GCP      100
2  3000  Azure      300


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "c_id": [1000,2000,2000,3000,3000], 
    "cloud":["Azure","GCP","Azure","AWS","Azure"], 
    "invoice":[200,200,300,100,100]
})
print (df2)
   c_id  cloud  invoice
0  1000  Azure      200
1  2000    GCP      200
2  2000  Azure      300
3  3000    AWS      100
4  3000  Azure      100
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['c_id','cloud'], as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
   c_id  cloud  invoice
0  1000  Azure      200
1  2000  Azure      300
2  2000    GCP      300
3  3000    AWS      100
4  3000  Azure      400
5  3000    GCP      100
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1.set_index(['c_id', 'cloud']).add(df2.set_index(['c_id', 'cloud']), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    c_id  cloud  invoice
0  1000  Azure   200.00
1  2000  Azure   300.00
2  2000    GCP   300.00
3  3000    AWS   100.00
4  3000  Azure   400.00
5  3000    GCP   100.00
```

Comment: So I'm not the one downvoting this, but this answer does not do it for me. I have a lot more columns other than just `invoice`

Comment: It will handle sum for other columns also. Please let me know a specific problem with this.

Comment: I got it right after following the other answer. Even so, thanks for your time!

Comment: @sagungrp I understand that other answer works fine. Please also check my updated answer.

Comment: I checked out your code, and it does run well in accord to my requirement